# Use a layer attribute in a generic dynamic SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have many raster layers that all look the same (same extent, all single-band). I'd like to write only one style (SLD) to specify the colors (colormap) to show in a WMS request. But if the different layers all will use the same colors, they do not have the same data range. For example, layer A goes from 0 to 100 and layer B, from -50 to -10.

I'd like to be able to write one sld file that first normalizes the data (through a ras:jiffle transformation for example) and then colors it with a generic colormap (a few "ColorMapEntry" lines going from 0 to 1).

Is there a way to store the data range (min and max) with the layer and to make it available to the rendering transformation in the dynamic SLD?

I see on the layer configuration page, at the very bottom, that I can modify the "minRange" and "maxRange" of the band in the coverage details. Is there a way for the SLD use these values?

My current solution has one generated SLD per layer, which is not optimal Moreover, if I want to add the possibility to change the colormap, I'll have to do this for each layer, which is again suboptimal.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want in an SLD file, but you might want to look at the SLD Rest service (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html#classify-raster-data) that might help you out.

Comment: This is indeed interesting! I hadn't seen it. That would require two requests, but that's not too bad. However, the biggest issue I see here is that the colormaps returned by this service seem limited to 2- and 3-color gradients. One of my goal is to specific and fancy colormaps depending on the variable, it wouldn't work here.

Comment: Using the "colors" parameter you can provide as many colors as you want, comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community module that has been designed with those requirements in mind:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/colormap/index.html

Statistics need to be gathered using gdalinfo and left there as a sidecar or the raster files.
Usual community module warnings apply: they are not officially maintained, nor included in releases (you'll have to grab a nightly build). Quoting the [GeoServer documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/index.html):

> Community modules are generally considered experimental in nature and are often under constant development. For that reason documentation in this section should not be considered solid or final and will be subject to change.